# Month wise data fetch from mysql database

Tags: php

[Month wise data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouORW.png)

Month wise data fetch from date field in mysql.

I have a table name salary_details and my table data looks like attached Image. Please see the image to solve my problem.

i am using following code of php.

"select *, SUM(amount) as amt from salary_details
group by month,name"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do pivot, check reference [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f0b2ed/pivot-and-unpovit-in-sql-server/#:%7E:text=Pivot%20and%20Unpivot%20in%20SQL%20are%20two%20relational%20operators%20that,column%20level%20to%20row%20level.)

```
SELECT Name, ['July'],['August'],['September'] FROM   
(SELECT Name, [Month] , Amount FROM salary_details )Tab1  
PIVOT  
(  
SUM(amount) FOR [Month] IN (['July'],['August'],['September'])
) AS Tab2  
ORDER BY Tab2.Name
```